# Trying to override formatting implementation of static method in compiled SDK

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am working with the Community Server framework.

One of the provided form controls allows the user to update his/her 'status'. For example: 'Joe: is going to get coffee  : 12:30am'.

I want to change the format of that message before it goes into the database(goes in as formatted HTML). I want to take out the ":" character between the name and the message - or perhaps do other formatting.

The formatting is completed via the 'UpdateStatusMessageForm' instantiating 'ActivityMessage' type with the status message the user entered. 'ActivityMessage' calls it's formatting method seen below:

```
public static string GetFormat(IActivityMessage message, string timeCssClass)
{
        return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>: {2} <span class='{3}'>{4}</span>", SiteUrls.Instance().UserProfile(message.Author.Username), message.Author.DisplayName, message.Body, timeCssClass, Formatter.FormatTime(message.DateCreated));

}
```

How can I change the implementation of that method if I can't override it? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can't override a static method.

The long answer and some workarounds are in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx)